# NotWritableException in Image.php line 143: Can't write image data to path

Tags: mysql, database, heroku, laravel-5, database-connection

I kept getting this error while trying migrate to Heroku

**heroku run php artisan migrate**

---

```
production.ERROR: PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory in /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:55
Stack trace:
#0 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php(55): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=;dbn...', NULL, NULL, Array)
#1 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/MySqlConnector.php(22): Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector->createConnection('mysql:host=;dbn...', Array, Array)
#2 /app/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(11387): Illuminate\Database\Connectors\MySqlConnector->connect(Array)
#3 /app/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(11383): Illuminate\Database\Connectors\ConnectionFactory->createSingleConnection(Array)
#4 /app/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(11298): Illuminate\Database\Connectors\ConnectionFactory->make(Array, 'mysql')
#5 /app/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(11253): Illuminate\Database\DatabaseManager->makeConnection('mysql')
#6 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/DatabaseMigrationRepository.php(171): Illuminate\Database\DatabaseManager->connection('mysql')
#7 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/DatabaseMigrationRepository.php(139): Illuminate\Database\Migrations\DatabaseMigrationRepository->getConnection()
#8 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/Migrator.php(393): Illuminate\Database\Migrations\DatabaseMigrationRepository->repositoryExists()
#9 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Console/Migrations/MigrateCommand.php(100): Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migrator->repositoryExists()
#10 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Console/Migrations/MigrateCommand.php(58): Illuminate\Database\Console\Migrations\MigrateCommand->prepareDatabase()
#11 [internal function]: Illuminate\Database\Console\Migrations\MigrateCommand->fire()
#12 /app/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(1181): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#13 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(150): Illuminate\Container\Container->call(Array)
#14 /app/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(256): Illuminate\Console\Command->execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#15 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(136): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#16 /app/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(838): Illuminate\Console\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#17 /app/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(189): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand(Object(Illuminate\Database\Console\Migrations\MigrateCommand), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#18 /app/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(120): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#19 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(107): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#20 /app/artisan(35): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#21 {main}  




  [PDOException]                                    
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
```

---

Here is my `database.php` config file

```
'mysql'       => [

            'driver'      => 'mysql',


            // 'host'        => env('DB_HOST'),
            // 'database'    => env('DB_DATABASE'),
            // 'username'    => env('DB_USERNAME'),
            // 'password'    => env('DB_PASSWORD'),
            // 'unix_socket' => env('UNIX_SOCKET'),


            'host'     => parse_url(getenv("DATABASE_URL"))["host"],
            'database' => substr(parse_url(getenv("DATABASE_URL"))["path"], 1),
            'username' => parse_url(getenv("DATABASE_URL"))["user"],
            'password' => parse_url(getenv("DATABASE_URL"))["pass"],


            'charset'     => 'utf8',
            'collation'   => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'      => '',
            'strict'      => false,
        ]
```

---

Here is my

```
CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL:
mysql://bd6a133a3b72510b:daa3335b90@us-cdbr-iron-east-04.cleardb.net/heroku_fd002f4569286b31?reconnect=true
```

What did I do wrong ? What else should I look into ?